# Why are there mobile workers missing from the CommCare application status report?

Tags: commcare

Is there a reason why I can see mobile workers in the worker activity report that I cannot see in the application status report on CommCare? For instance I can see 254 users in a current worker activity report, but I can only see 250 in the application status report?

Answer (score 3):

In order to have the mobile workers that you have created show up in the application status report the mobile worker must have successfully submitted a form to the server. This is not the case for the worker activity report; with the worker activity report you should see all of your mobile workers regardless of submissions.

It's important to note that even if you have assigned cases to your mobile workers, if they haven't submitted data against any of those cases, you will not be able to see them in the application status report. Also if you have archived mobile workers they will not show up in the app status report

Comment: This is correct.  It's also the case that if you select an app, only users who have submitted forms on that app will appear in the application status report.

Answer (score 0):

Claire's answer is mostly correct but leaves out one other way mobile workers get added to the application status report, a sync with the server. Each time a user syncs the application status report is updated with last sync time, and if that is more recent than the last form submission, application version information and commcare version information are taken from the last sync.